# File / stream saver directly from WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I have some WASM code that produces several MB of text output that needs to be saved to a file. My general question is what is a memory and time efficient way of producing a file client-side from WASM code?

Ideally, the WASM code itself would print to the file stream to avoid any JS overhead. However, with JS, I can use something like [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js), but wonder if it's possible/makes sense to avoid storing the whole file in memory *before* writing. That is, should this write in, say, 1 kB increments or similar? If so, one option is to adapt the [Write as you type](https://jimmywarting.github.io/StreamSaver.js/examples/plain-text.html) example to take in 1 kB strings passed from WASM.

Comment: Seems to depend on what is the purpose of the topic text file, check File System spec from Emscripten along with its api https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#filesystem-api-filesystems.

Comment: Thanks @RyszardGrzesica, though it looks like none of the currently supported file systems support writing to disk via an interface akin to a file download. StreamSaver.js does this. I'll try to post an answer for how to use StreamSaver.js at some point.